# How to map all urls to a single .html page

Tags: java, javascript, html, url, tomcat

I'm new to Tomcat, and understand servlet-mapping, but was hoping I could do some mapping to a html file residing in the webapp/ folder.

I have a simple javascript web application that resides as webapp/index.html. Since I'm messing with the url in javascript, I want to make it possible to map /console/* to hit webapp/index.html. For example /console/hi and /console/bye should both load up webapp/index.html.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I think that what you need is a *filter*, for a particular family of URLs, and that filter can do the redirecting/forwarding as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can change your index.html file to same index.jsp file
and then use this mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/console/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I think it is the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Pointy said, you'll need a filter, that will receive all requests and redirect to the .hmtl page you want...

Here is a [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat/) with a simple filter implementation.

Hope it helps

Comment: the linked implementation is not more than a hello world, not showing how to redirect and how to handle existing files

Answer (score 1):

I've published a Java servlet filter implementation that does what you need to Github. The code is pretty simple, and I expect you might want to customize it to your own needs.

https://github.com/lookfirst/history-api-fallback